# Why rails route _path / _url variables that require an id do not in tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, minitest

```rb
  test "should start user_course" do
    @user = users(:one)
    sign_in @user

    @user_course = @user.user_courses.first
    get user_course_url(@user_course)
    assert_redirected_to start_user_course_section_url
  end
```

when the start_user_course_section_url route is:

```rb
  resources :user_course_sections do
    member do
      get :start
    end
  end
```

and this route requires an id everywhere except this test and the test is passing.

Any help would be great!

EDIT:
This is what rails routes returns:

```
Prefix            | start_user_course_section
Verb              | GET
URI               | /ss/:id/start(.:format)
Controller#Action | user_course_sections#start
```

Comment: Check that `rails routes` shows the parameter correctly, and secondly, worth checking out what that method actually returns as it might not be what you expect.

Comment: Yes the rails routes show params correctly i just updated the question to include that.

Comment: It's worth checking what string value you get when calling the `_url` function that way. Like you, I'd expect an error, but there can be surprises! I'd also want to be sure that `assert` line fires, as it might be skipped for some reason. It's always a good idea to test that the test can fail, so maybe change that to something completely wrong to see if it picks up on it correctly.

Comment: Seems like when i run `get user_course_url(@user_course)` it automaticly sets the id for future requests with that `@user_course.id` is that something rails automaticly does?

Comment: This could be a quirk of the testing environment, as that's not how it works in the usual case.